# How to run a shell (bash) script automatically at startup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

As the question states, what is the best/recommended way of running a bash script after I login the OS? I’m using Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit `.bash_profile` if you just want it for yourself or edit `/etc/profile` if you want to enforce it for everyone.

Comment: That'd be `~/.bash_profile` (i.e. in the home directory, just clarifying)